# Scanning char validating with while

Tags: java, while-loop

The complex condition in the `while` (check if there is input, and if its different to `m` or `f`) is not working:

```
System.out.println("Insert gender (m / f)  ");
while (!stdin.hasNext() & !(temp = stdin.next()).equals("m") & !(temp.equals("f"))) {
    System.out.println("try again");stdin.nextLine();
}
inpSexo = temp.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bitwise comparison `&` operator in the `while()` condition.
You should be using logical `&&` operator.

```
while (stdin.hasNext() && !(temp = stdin.next()).equals("m") && !(temp.equals("f")))
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. However, i used the boolean valid because eclipse throws uninitialized variable on temp. Thanks!

Comment: You can always initialize variable in declaration i.e  `String temp = "";`

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet should achieve what you want:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean valid = false;
        String input;

        while (!valid){

            System.out.println("Insert gender (m / f)  ");
            input = s.nextLine();
            System.out.println("User entered: " + input);
            if ((input.equalsIgnoreCase("m")) || (input.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))){
                valid = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use this:

```
class check{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter Sex (M/F): ");
            String s = in.readLine();
            if(s.compareTo("M")==0){
                System.out.print("Male");
            }
            if(s.compareTo("F")==0){
                System.out.print("F");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid input!!!")
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IO ERROR !!!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```